# How can I properly test an envoyfilter enforcing max_stream_duration and max_connection_duration timeouts under a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I am currently trying to apply a filter that enforces `max_stream_duration` and `max_connection_duration` timeouts. The pods these need to apply to are sitting underneath a Kubernetes service. They are set to deny all traffic not coming from this service. I *believe* I have the filter configured correctly, but have been unable to get the desired responses.

For all tests below, I set the timeout to 1s, and then ensured that the total time the request took was longer. All three tests described below return a "200-success", even if they take 20+ seconds.

I have tried to use an envoyfilter set with `http.fault` to introduce some lag.
I have tried to use a virutalservice to cause a delay.
I have tried to create a file that takes more than 1s to transfer, and then transfer the file.

What is the recommended way to do this?

The filter, as I currently have it configured.  The filter does not give me errors when I apply it.  I wasn't able to copy/paste this out of my work environment, so I typed this out.  If there are formatting/typo errors, that's where they came from.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: myFilter
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      label: myLabel
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manger"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed:config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
          common_http_protocol-options:
            max_connection_duration: 1s
            max_stream_duration: 1s
```